# How to detect whether my JSON string has escaped HTML tags in Java

Tags: java, json, encoding

I am trying to write a unit test in Java to test encoded JSON values. I am trying to do the following:

```
assertEquals(expectedJSON(),actualJSON())
```

where *expectedJSON()* returns

```
{
    "someHtml": {
        "html": "<html>HTML&CSS</html>"
    }
}
```

where as *actualJSON()* returns

```
 {
        "someHtml": {
            "html": "\u003Chtml\u003EHTML\u0026CSS\u003C/html\u003E"
        }
    }
```

I want the expectedJSON to return what the actualJSON() is returning, but I am not able to figure out an easy way to do this. I've looked online, but haven't found anything easily on this. The *actualJSON()* is doing some complex processing and needs to return the value this way. My *expectedJSON()* method looks like this

```
public String expectedJSONWithHTMLValues(){
        return "{" +
                    "\"someHtml\":{" +
                  "\"html\":\"\u003Chtml\u003EHTML\u0026CSS\u003C/html\u003E\"}}";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need actual json text to match? Shouldn't the only thing that matters be the values your deserializers produce?

Comment: Yes, it does seem that way, but i could just have my actualJSON() return "<html>HTML&CSS</html>" and test still passes, so the test is not good enough. I want to make sure that acutalJSON() actually returns the escaped JSON values. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to the other answer, `\u` escapes have an interesting property in Java where they are actually *preprocessed* by the compiler ([JLS §3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)).

By this, I mean that `\u` characters are replaced in the source file *before* going to the compiler. Therefore, your code:

```
public String expectedJSONWithHTMLValues(){
    return "{" +
           "\"someHtml\":{" +
           "\"html\":\"\u003Chtml\u003EHTML\u0026CSS\u003C/html\u003E\"}}";
}
```

Is being preprocessed to:

```
public String expectedJSONWithHTMLValues(){
    return "{" +
           "\"someHtml\":{" +
           "\"html\":\"<html>HTML&CSS</html>\"}}";
}
```

And *that* is what's being compiled.

The Java compiler will turn any `\u` escapes into the character prior to actually compiling the file. This means that `\u` escapes can be used in variable names, class names, method names, and so on. The compiler will turn it into the character itself and use it in the compiling process. This is why you're supposed to use `\n` in your strings instead of `\u000a`. If you used the latter, the source code would go from something like this:

```
String s = "My\u000aNewline";
```

To this:

```
String s = "My
Newline";
```

Which would cause a compiler error since the `String` literal is split across multiple lines.

This can allow you to do some extremely bad things. For example, this is 100% legal Java code and will compile on any operating system:

```
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063 \u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073 \u004d\u0061\u0069\u006e \u007b

    \u0070\u0072\u0069\u0076\u0061\u0074\u0065 \u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063 \u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067 \u0073\u006f\u006d\u0065\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067 \u003d \u0022\u004d\u0079 \u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u0022\u003b

    \u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063 \u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063 \u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064 \u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d \u0061\u0072\u0067\u0073\u0029 \u007b
        \u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u006c\u006e\u0028\u0073\u006f\u006d\u0065\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u0029\u003b
    \u007d
\u007d
```

It prints:

```
My String
```

Don't believe me? [See for yourself.](http://ideone.com/yVGwiz) The compiler first converted all `\u` escapes into characters, which takes everything like `\u0070\u0072\u0069\u0076\u0061\u0074\u0065` and transforms it into `private`, or `\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067` into `String`.

Anyway, to fix your particular issue, all you need to do is double-escape the `\` like so:

```
public String expectedJSONWithHTMLValues(){
    return "{" +
           "\"someHtml\":{" +
           "\"html\":\"\\u003Chtml\\u003EHTML\\u0026CSS\\u003C/html\\u003E\"}}";
}
```

It's also worth noting that this String:

```
{"someHtml":{"html":"\u003Chtml\u003EHTML\u0026CSS\u003C/html\u003E"}}
```

Is not equal to this String with the whitespace added in:

```
{
    "someHtml": {
        "html": "\u003Chtml\u003EHTML\u0026CSS\u003C/html\u003E"
    }
}
```

`String.equals` will include whitespace in the equality, so make sure that your two strings are identical character-by-character, including whitespace.

Comment: Thank you Brian, that was a great explanation

Answer (score 1):

The backslash has special meaning in `String` constants not only when you write `"\""` but also when you write something like `"\u003C"`. In the latter case the sequence `\u003C` is replaced by the Unicode character U+003C which is `'<'`. If you want to have the literal sequence `\u003C` you have to quote the backslash itself to insert the backslash character in the `String` constant: `"\\u003C"`.

Note that your `String` matching still might fail due to the whitespace differences. Since that whitespace is ignorable from a JSON point of view it’s not a good idea to perform exact `String` matching for JSON values.

Comment: `\u` actually has special meaning *anywhere in a Java source file* - not just in a String constant

Comment: That’s right `\u` has a special meaning everywhere. But here it’s still the simple situation that it requires two backslashes to insert a literal backslash into a `String`.

Comment: @artbristol Not only that, but unicode escapes even have different semantics than the other escape sequences like `\n` or `\t`, as I demonstrate in my answer.